# Finding Numbers in Brackets and Summing Them

Tags: regular-expressions, commands

**QUESTION:**

How can I make an emacs command `M-x sum-the-brackets` that scans highlighted text for all occurrences of `[ <number> u ]` and `[ <number>u ]`,  and sums them?

**EXAMPLE:**

Selecting the text

```
Here is some text. [0.1u]
Here is some more text [0.2 u]
And here is some noise: 0.2
```

and running `M-x sum-the-brackets` should yield `0.3` in the mini-buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to search for all instances of the regular expression `\[ *\([-0-9.]+\) *u *\]`:

```
(re-search-forward "\\[ *\\([-0-9.]+\\) *u *\\]" nil t)
```

and sum the matches:

```
(setq sum (+ sum (string-to-number (match-string 1))))
```

Since you want this to apply to the region only, you'll need to `narrow-to-region` and then restore the restriction using `save-restriction`.

Putting this all together, we get:

```
(defun my-sum (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion
      (narrow-to-region begin end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((sum 0))
        (while (re-search-forward "\\[ *\\([-0-9.]+\\) *u *\\]" nil t)
          (setq sum (+ sum (string-to-number (match-string 1)))))
        (message "%s" sum)
        sum))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using standard commands:

```
M-: (setq n 0) RET
C-M-% \[\([0-9.]+\) *u\] RET \,(prog1 \& (setq n (+ n \#1))) RET !
M-: n RET
```

*Note*: to get more information have a look at help for `query-replace-regexp`, `prog1` and `eval-expression`

Comment: This is cool, I didn't know this replacement style is possible. I corrected your answer and made a remark about finding more help. Please review my edit to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function you wished for.
I put some extra variables inside this function, so it is easier for you to enhance it.

```
(defun sum-the-brackets (begin end)
    "sums up values in brackets with style '[ FLOAT u ]'
For non interactive use BEGIN must be smaller then END.
If FLOAT is omitted bracket counts with value one
If FLOAT is '.' it counts as value 0
Whitespace inside the brackets is ignored"
    (interactive "r")
    (save-excursion
        (let ((n 0)       ; desired value
              (c 0)       ; counter
              (tmp nil)   ; string in bracket
              (tmpf 0))   ; value of string in bracket
            (goto-char begin)
            (while (search-forward-regexp "\\[ *\\([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*\\) *\\(u *\\)\\]" end t)
                (setq c (1+ c))
                (setq tmp (match-string 1))
                (setq tmpf (if (string= "" tmp) 1                              
                               (string-to-number tmp)))
                (setq n (+ n tmpf)))
            (message "Sum-Value: %2.3f ; brackets counted: %d" n c))))
```

This function sums up following 6 brackets to value 3.6:

```
Here is some text. [0.1u]
Here is some more text [ 0.2 u]
count me with value zero point 3 [.3 u]
count me with value two [2 u]
count me with value one [u]
count me with zero [ . u ]
And here is some noise: 0.2
```

*Note*: **politza answer is way more cool. :)**

*Note2*: comments/edits on improvement of the code are very welcome, I did code this for practice and it took me a while. :)

**Edit**: the user "jch" changed the question. I will not update this answer because "jch" gave an answer which fits his edits and maybe someone else finds my answer useful.

Comment: 1. Is narrowing really necessary ? 2. Second argument of `search-forward-regexp` you gave is also the default. 3. It's always nice beeing able to use a command as function as well, i.e. use `(begin end)` arguments and setup interactive usage in the `(interactive)` spec appropriately.

Comment: @politza many thanks for your constructive comment! I changed the code accordingly. Also I spotted, that the questioner  wanted to evaluate `[u]`.

Comment: The apparent `[u]` in the orignal answer was a typo, due to some misquoted markup.  I merely fixed the markup, which caused the spurious `[u]` to disapper.  As to your answer — please keep it around, it's good to have multiple solutions written in different styles.

Comment: You also wrote a good and correct answer, so there is no need to have a correct answer a second time. Besides, my original code, before my edit looks nearly the same like yours and I don't want to revert my code. Everything is fine! :)